# map not asking for permission

Tags: objective-c, permissions, ios7, maps, mapkit

I am using [map from here](https://github.com/digdog/MapKitDragAndDrop) to pin the location.

All is working perfectly except only 1 point as below.

When I open map for first time, it ask for permission BUT get's away within half second and I can't see again the popun window of permission in app.

Also it sets OFF for Location in Setting.

Any idea why this is happening?

I am trying this on iPhone with iOS 7.

Xcode I am using is Xcode 5. Base sdk is iOS 7.

---

I just tested with iOS 6/ iPhone 5.

There also its showing for a second and getting away. I have to manually set permission in setting.

---

When I use new code from [here](http://www.codigator.com/tutorials/mapkit-tutorial-for-ios-beginners/), its working. Map is asking for permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damn!!! I can't believe it...

**Shows Users Location** was un-ticked.

Once I tick that, its working fine.

Is this really a problem??